# Structure node.js project by component

Tags: node.js, architecture, structure

I'm trying to structure my Nodejs project by component, following this Nodejs best practice [repo](https://github.com/goldbergyoni/nodebestpractices/blob/master/sections/projectstructre/breakintcomponents.md).

So my question is, how can i place an `Order` and update the `Product` items left in db. Should i use `ProductsService` inside `Order` component.

Have anyone already implemented this approach? Can you give me some example.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If ProductsService contains a method or function that is exported, you should use this exported function inside of the Order component to update the products in the database.

Example

mymodule.js

```
// exported function
const myFunction = function(foo) {
  if(foo) {
    return bar;
  }
}

module.exports = myFunction;
```

index.js

```
const myModule = require('./mymodule.js');
// using the function
myModule(value);
```